# Change Text of elements by clicking it. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have button and when I click it a html page loads to div with id=myDiv. Then I want to change the text of certain tags when they are clicked. Like if i click the text that is in h2 tag the text of the h2 tag change to some sting.

"My Page" would be "Text Removed" after i clicked "My Page".

Been trying to use text() to change the text, but now always when i click on the area of myDiv the whole html page disappear and my div have only the string "Text Removed"

How can i access every tag in the div so i can click on single text inside of

and change it to "text removed"?

Comment: some code would be handy

Comment: if you want to change a specific h2 tag for instance your should give that tag an own id and call that id. Or have I misundersttod your question?

Comment: Are the elements you want to add the click events for generated through jQuery?

Comment: some code would be handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('*', '#myDiv').live('click', function() {
    $(this).text('Text removed');
});
```

should do it.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Of course, if OP only wants to edit *certain* tags inside of `myDiv` instead of *all* tags, this won't work. In that case I would assign a class -- say, `. removable ` -- for every tag that should be.

Comment: You'll want to throw a `return false;` at the end there.  Otherwise, clicking on a nested element will wipe out everything up to the root.  http://jsfiddle.net/uRGup/